# Cursor.lockState working differently in Unity versus in my WebGL build

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

In Unity `Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;` moves the cursor to the center of the screen, hides the cursor and locks it there. This is super useful because I'm using the FPScontroller to be able to look around and interact with UI elements in a 3D space by aiming my cross-hair at them and casting a ray.

Problem is when I upload the project to simmer.io it slightly differently in the browser. Switching between `Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.none;` and `Locked` works except the cursor is locked at its current position--its never moved back to the center of the screen, ie. where my cross-hair is. Once the hidden cursor and the cross-hair are misaligned all my mouseover and raycast commands stop working.

Project can be found here, for the interested. To test the buggy behavior use TAB to toggle the pause menu. https://simmer.io/@AndreM/archtour

Comment: Why do you need the cursor to be perfectly centered? Typically first person locked-state games should use mouse-delta to control the cross-hair/camera.

Comment: There are gameObjects I want to respond to "OnMouseEnter" function. Looking back at it, that was my only reason. So maybe if I solve that in another way I could be free from this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Simmer.io uses a modifies `UnityPlayer.js` and its behaviour may differ from what the expected behaviour in a standard Unity WebGL build will be. Contact them with this issue instead. Generally, there will be bugginess in Chrome for advanced features like this.